# Grails and JQuery, how to use local storage to handle session timeout dialog with mutiple tabs

Tags: jquery, grails, local-storage

I have a grails application which I would like to show a session timeout dialog based on local storage, so that multiple browser tabs are covered. resetting the timeout as different tabs are accessed. Do you have an example of this, preferably in JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followup: I ended up doing the below to solve this:

```
WebIl.Session = [];
var sess_pollInterval = 60000;
var sess_intervalID;
var sess_expirationMinutes;

WebIl.Session.setupExpiration = function (timeout) {
   sess_expirationMinutes = Math.floor(timeout/60);
  initSession();
};

function initSession() {
  localStorage.timeout = new Date();
  sessSetInterval();
  $(document).ajaxStart(function (ed, e) {
    sessKeyPressed(ed, e);
  });
}
function sessSetInterval() {
  sess_intervalID = setInterval('sessInterval()', sess_pollInterval);
}
function sessClearInterval() {
  clearInterval(sess_intervalID);

}
function sessKeyPressed(ed, e) {
  localStorage.timeout = new Date();
}

function sessInterval() {
  //stop the timer
  now = new Date();
  diff = now - Date.parse(localStorage.timeout);
//  alert("now: " + now + "  local: " + Date.parse(localStorage.timeout) );
//alert("diff: "+ diff);
  diffMins = (diff / 1000 / 60);
//  alert("before timed out dif mins: " + diffMins + "  sess timeout: " + sess_expirationMinutes );
  if (diffMins > sess_expirationMinutes) {
    sessClearInterval();
    //show dialog
    openMessage('Session has timed out. All unsaved changes have been lost.'+
            ' You will be automatically logged back in through the single sign-on process', 'notice');
  }
}
```